# Modify model data from threads in in PyQt

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyside, nuke

I'm having trouble when modifying the source model of a QSortFilterProxyModel from another thread, while the proxy model is connected to a view. The proxy model seems to add "ghost" items to the model being displayed, blank items that cannot be interacted with (apparently)

This example code demonstrates the problem I'm experiencing, reduced down to a bare-basic example where there's a view for each of the proxy model and the source model:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import random


WordList = ["apples", "pears", "down", "stairs", "mother", "hubord", "isn't", "cupboard", "lemon", "tango", "apricot", "nuke"]

class Searcher(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(Searcher, self).__init__()
        self.model = model

    def run(self):
        populateModel(self.model)


def populateModel(model):
    for i in range(5):
        item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        model.invisibleRootItem().appendRow(item1)
        majorWord = random.choice(WordList)
        item1.setData(majorWord, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)

        for i in range(random.randint(2, 8)):
            item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            item1.appendRow(item2)
            item2.setData(os.path.join(majorWord, random.choice(WordList)), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tv = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
    tv.setWindowTitle("Source Model, Threaded")
    tv.show()

    tv2 = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
    tv2.setWindowTitle("Proxy Model, Threaded")
    tv2.show()

    tv3 = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
    tv3.setWindowTitle("Proxy Model 2, No Threading")
    tv3.show()

    sourceModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    tv.setModel(sourceModel)

    proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
    proxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
    proxyModel.setSourceModel(sourceModel)
    tv2.setModel(proxyModel)

    s = Searcher(sourceModel)
    s.start()

    sm3 = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    pm3 = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
    pm3.setSourceModel(sm3)
    proxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
    tv3.setModel(pm3)
    populateModel(sm3)
```

I thought that maybe the `setDynamicSortFilter` property of the proxy model could be useful, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Any help or pointers appreciated!

Comment: Qt does not support gui operations of any kind outside the main thread. Since a model and its items are gui elements, you cannot safely create them in another thread. If you want to improve performance, use a custom model.

Comment: You can not modify the GUI directly from another thread, besides I do not see the need to do it since adding elements to a model does not consume much time. One option is to use QMetaObject::invokedMethod() but it is equivalent to execute it in the main thread and in your case it generates a more unnecessary load, so it is best that you execute that code in the GUI thread.

Comment: @eyllanesc, thanks for your help! I didn't actually realise that data models were considered a part of the GUI, so thought it should have been fine to adjust as just a data structure. The reason I was adding to the model was because I'm running a pretty heavy IO function to populate my model (this is just a lightweight example). I'm guessing that a better approach would be to run the function in another thread and emit the result as a signal picked up and added to the model by the main thread?

Comment: @Mitchell Exactly, that's the right approach

Comment: @Mitchell On the other hand keep in mind that in reality the problem is not in itself that is part of the GUI but the model is a QObject and this is not thread-safe so you only have to modify it in the thread where it was created and as the This model is closely related to the view both must live in the same thread since the interaction is high.